# Is logistic regression the best test for this study?

Tags: regression, logistic

I have two independent variables (both categorical) and one dependent (categorical) variable.  I want to look at the predictive factor or significance of those two independent variables (either separately or combined) on the dependent variable.  Is logistic regression the test I need to use? What if I run this same test on three different groups?

Comment: You should try $\chi^2$ for contigency tables, logistic regression or loglinear models.

Answer (score -1):

Logistic regression is meant for continuous independent variables. The textbook approach in your case is to use a chi-squared test of independence. To omit a variable, just add together the cell counts for cells that differ only in the omitted variable.

A reference:
http://stattrek.com/chi-square-test/independence.aspx?Tutorial=AP

Comment: Can I use chi-square if I have more than one independent variable?

Comment: Yes. You would form the table by listing all possible combinations of the independent variables you have along one axis, then listing the values of the dependent variable along the other.


I am new to CV, so if the down-voter would like to make a suggestion, I will gladly consider it.